# apicontroller not getting from ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I get "404 Not Found" on doing a  Ajax call ,
maybe that I don't understand how routing works ...

```
function ApproveAlert(ID) {
     $.ajaxPost('/api/DeviceApi/ApproveAlertNew', { 'ID': ID }, function (data) {
        ... get error "404 Not Found"
    }, null);
}
```

in my mvc4 C# app I have a rout config :

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "defaultapiaction",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
             );
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "defaultapiid",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
             );
```

and apicontroller :

```
public class DeviceApiController : ApiController
    {
        //
        // GET: /DeviceApi/
        [HttpPost]
        public bool ApproveAlertNew(int ID)
        {
            ..do
        }
```

Comment: Try with `$.post('/api/DeviceApi/ApproveAlertNew?ID=' + ID, {}, function(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Web API controllers don't use "Actions" in the same sense that MVC controllers do. Web API controllers also don't really use `[HttpPost]`, `[HttpGet]` attributes either. They dispatch requests based on the names of the methods inside of the ApiControllers. I suggest to read up a little more on Web API differences from MVC as it is similar but sometimes hard to get up and running...

Here's some pretty generic examples from a Web API that I made for testing. I do not have JavaScript to post to this API because I was posting from a .NET WPF app. You would post to "/Important" NOT "/Important/Post" Hopefully this will get you on the right track...

WebAPIConfig.cs (Routes):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ArrayTest.WebAPI
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

API Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using ArrayTest.Models;
using System.Threading;

namespace ArrayTest.WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class ImportantController : ApiController
    {
        // POST api/important
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(ImportantList values)
        {
            //manipulate values received from client
            for (int i = 0; i < values.ImportantIDs.Count; i++)
            {
                values.ImportantIDs[i] = values.ImportantIDs[i] * 2;
            }

            //perhaps save to database, send emails, etc... here.

            Thread.Sleep(5000); //simulate important work

            //in my case I am changing values and sending the values back here.
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, values);
        }

    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ArrayTest.Models
{
    public class ImportantList
    {
        public List<int> ImportantIDs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with:

```
function ApproveAlert(ID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/api/DeviceApi/ApproveAlertNew",
        data: {
            ID: ID
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //Handle your success
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //Handle error
        }
    });
}
```